# Duplicate filter values in a calculated column

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, calculated-column

I have a document library with a calculated column.  This document library is populated from a windows service.  Every time a new document is added, the calculated column has a formula to choose whether it is AM or PM.  My problem is when I want to filter the calculated column, it has multiple values of AM and PM.

[image: Duplicate filter values]

When I change the returned data type of the calculated column, the filter problem gets fixed (meaning one AM and one PM) but when a new document gets added, the problem comes back.

Has anybody encountered the same?  Any ideas or suggestions are appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you paste here your calculated column formula?

Comment: Here it is: =IF(HOUR([Shift Start Date / Time])<12,"AM","PM")

Answer (score 0):

Your comment says your date column is called [Shift Start Date / Time], so this calculated column formula outputs AM or PM:

```
=TEXT([Shift Start Date / Time],"AM/PM")
```

I tested this on a custom list and it works for me.

SOURCE:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/text-function-HP010062580.aspx